# interpolate function does not fill nan values in data frame

Tags: python, interpolation, missing-data

Good evening, I have a problem filling in the missing data in a data frame.

I want to fill the ESG missing data of each company with the function interpolate if the number of missing values is between 1 and 6 and drop the column if there are more than 6 missing values.

The code runs, but it does not fill the Nan values.

```
import pandas as pd

#make the file available for everyone from the drive

sp500_esg_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/132LPUsd4Gh4eM0eOHRA9XQsuYIeFO34Z/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=109030301512511343656&rtpof=true"
file_id1 = sp500_esg_url.split("/")[-2]
export = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="
path2 = export + file_id1

#read second file
sp500_esg = pd.read_excel(path2)

#rename date column for esg
wrongindex2 = sp500_esg.columns[0]
sp500_esg = sp500_esg.rename(columns = {wrongindex2:"Date"})

#set date column as index
sp500_esg = sp500_esg.set_index('Date', drop = True)

#make a copy
try1 = sp500_esg.copy()

#resample from daily to yearly
try1 = try1.resample('Y').mean()

#count total NaN in each column
print(try1.isnull().sum())

def interpolate_func(try1):
    for column in try1.columns:
            # Count the number of missing values in the column
            missing_count = try1[column].isna().sum()

            # If the number of missing values is between 1 and 6, interpolate to fill missing values
            if 1 <= missing_count <= 6:
                try1[column] = try1[column].interpolate()

            # If the number of missing values is greater than 6, drop the column
            elif missing_count > 6:
                try1 = try1.drop(column, axis=1)

    return try1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

I tried to specify the arguments of the interpolate function, with no results

Comment: What is the output (of your print-function) ? In your example you never called the `interpolate_func`. Please post a [example] with an example dataframe, so that we can run your code - we don't have your excel-file.

Comment: The result of the print function is the same as if I had not run the function. I have added the database in the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue specifying the following inside the function interpolate:

```
def interpolate_func(try1):
    '''
    Function that check NaN amount per each column and either drop the column if NaN > 6 or
    fill it with interpolation method if 1 <= NaN <= 6
    '''
    for column in try1.columns:
            missing_count = try1[column].isnull().sum()
            if 1 <= missing_count <= 6:
                try1[column] = try1[column].astype(float).interpolate(limit_direction='both')
            elif missing_count > 6:
                try1 = try1.drop(column, axis=1)
    return try1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the raw data but I don't see anything wrong with your code. Here is a small code that does what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,None, None]*4, 'b':[3,4,None,5]*4, 'c':[6,7,8,9]*4})
print(df)
for column in df.columns:
    n = df[column].isna().sum()
    if n > 6:
        df.drop(columns=column, inplace=True)
    elif 1 <  n < 6:
        df[column] = df[column].interpolate()      
print(df)

      a    b  c
0   1.0  3.0  6
1   2.0  4.0  7
2   NaN  NaN  8
3   NaN  5.0  9
4   1.0  3.0  6
5   2.0  4.0  7
6   NaN  NaN  8
7   NaN  5.0  9
8   1.0  3.0  6
9   2.0  4.0  7
10  NaN  NaN  8
11  NaN  5.0  9
12  1.0  3.0  6
13  2.0  4.0  7
14  NaN  NaN  8
15  NaN  5.0  9
      b  c
0   3.0  6
1   4.0  7
2   4.5  8
3   5.0  9
4   3.0  6
5   4.0  7
6   4.5  8
7   5.0  9
8   3.0  6
9   4.0  7
10  4.5  8
11  5.0  9
12  3.0  6
13  4.0  7
14  4.5  8
15  5.0  9
```

Comment: I tried also this version but it does not work, I updated the question with database's link :)

Comment: What do you get when you call `interpolate_func(try1)`? `try1` has 2349 rows × 504 columns before and 9 rows × 501 columns after. I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: the 2 columns with more than 6 missing values are deleted but there still are missing values in the dataframe